# How to hide or block the navigation bar or 3 main button

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I know that there are many many posts for my question , but they don't work really, as I've tried many solutions.

I would like that my title Bar (1) stays on the top normally AND my **navigation bar (2)** is hidden or blocked.
I'm developing an application where the back button, home button, and app button are not allowed to be clicked. (the three buttons are locked or hidden)
I already use :

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
```

But the other buttons stay available. Please see the attached picture to get a better understanding.

[Click here to see my screenshot](http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_804741Sanstitre.png)

Comment: So called Status bar is supposedly an Action Bar, so just don't create an Action Bar in your Activity: 
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();

Comment: https://developers.google.com/live/shows/4616065141178368 Check romain's video. Well worth it.

Comment: i already use the actionBar.hide , but there is the title bar ((1) in my picture) who disappear , not the (2)